# hibernate composite-id returns null results

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbm, hbmxml, hbm2java

Just before anyone down rate this question, I want to say i have tried to search an answer for this problem for 2 days now without any answers. I have tried a lot but could not resolve it so posting it here. I have created a view in mysql DB. Using hbm2hbmxml in maven I generated hbm and pojo files for this view. This is my code to query the view in mysql DB. Need to know why it is returning null.

```
    public List<VListingdetail> getListingDomainByUserId(int userId) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    List<VListingdetail> listingDomains = new ArrayList<VListingdetail>();
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        String whereClause = "from VListingdetail where primaryfile=1 and userId='" + userId + "'";
        Query result = session.createQuery(whereClause);
        List list = result.list();
        for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            listingDomains.add((VListingdetail)it.next());
        }
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return listingDomains;
}
```

the results returns 3 rows but all of them are null
[image]

Here is the screen shot of hbm file
[image]

Here is the pojo file
[image]

Comment: How can you make an hibernate query on `VListingdetail` and not prefix (with `id`) the fields of `VListingdetailId` in the where clause ?

Comment: @PierreDemeestere even if i use String whereClause = "from VListingdetail"; its the same issue